# Array of enums with integers

Tags: c#, arrays, virtual-machine

I am making simple Virtual Machine. I have a enum type called `Instructions`.

```
public enum Instructions : int { 
    ADD = 1,
    SUB = 2,
    PUSH = 3,
    POP = 4,
    HALT = 5
}
```

In my test class i create a array of `Instructions` enum and i want to use `int` in that array like below.

```
Instructions[] code = new Instructions[] {
    PUSH, 2,
    PUSH, 7,
    ADD,
    POP,
    HALT  
};
```

My goal is read all instructions above and handle them. For example above code should do pushes 2 and 7 to the stack, then add them together and pop top of the stack.

It gives me error for `int` literal, and that is the error message.

```
Cannot implicity convert 'int' to 'Vm.Instructions'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How can i use `int` literals in my `Instructions` array?

Comment: Just like the error hints, you have to cast the numbers. You're going to have a hell of a time trying to parse any of that because your `2` is the same as `SUB` on your instructions.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually want an array of `Instructions`; you want an array of `int`, some of which are `Instructions`. Might want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2 and 7 are not of the type `Instructions`, you cannot put them in the `Instructions[]` array. You instead need an integer array.

Comment: Or cast them to `Instructions`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I changed Instructions array to int array. Then cast Instructions into int.